# C# MongoDB Atlas, I want to read indexlist in a cluster and write another cluster

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am a jr. DBA and i want to seek my devolopers index creating event. That's why I tried several solutions (adf, powershell etc.) and I thought I could handle this by writing a small application in c#.

Below is a query I use on mongosh, I want to read this query in a cluster and write it to a different cluster.

```
    db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1}).databases;


dbs.forEach(function(database) {
db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);
cols = db.getCollectionNames();

cols.forEach(function(col) {

     indexes = db[col].getIndexes();

     indexes.forEach(function(idx) {
        print("Database:" + database.name + " | Collection:" +col+ " | Index:" + idx.name);
       
         });});});
```

I am open to any help and suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: `collection.Indexes.List` (or `ListAsync`) to get the indexes as a collection of `BsonDocument`, and then use the implicit cast to `IndexKeysDefinition<collectionType>` from `BsonDocument` to create the index in another collection?

Comment: My intention is not to create those indexes in a collection in a different cluster, but only to collect the names of the existing indexes under a collection.

Comment: Oh, then use `List` or `ListAsync`.